# Nothing happens when trying to restart Apache

Tags: command-line, apache2, mysql

I'm trying to restart Apache, and when I use the command `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`, nothing happens. There is no error message or other response from the terminal whatsoever, after I hit enter it just goes to a new line. I have no idea what could be happening, the same thing happens when I try to restart mysql. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about other commands, like `sudo systemctl status apache2`  or `sudo systemctl is-active apache2`or `sudo systemctl reload-or-restart apache2`?

Comment: Those work fine. Apache is running okay, but I need to restart it to configure WordPress.

Comment: Isn't `sudo systemctl reload-or-restart apache2` sufficient for that?

Comment: Actually it appears that that one is doing the same thing. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? `lsb_release -a` if you need to find out.

Comment: 16.04 I believe.

Comment: `sudo apache2ctl restart` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

this also works with many other things like networking. Which would be

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: This worked, although WordPress still isn't configured correctly....

Answer (score 3):

Typically, if you start/restart apache, there is no confirmation given that it has started, though will advise if errors were encountered.

As shown with previous answers there could be a number of methods to start apache, based on the version of Ubuntu you are on.

Ubuntu 16.10, then following methods apply:

```
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

If concerned if it started properly, with either of the above commands, replace `restart` with `status`.

It should provide with a result similar to this if running:

```
    ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-03-22 00:38:10 UTC; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─1627 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1630 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─1631 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Mar 22 00:38:09 potato systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Mar 22 00:38:09 potato apache2[1605]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar 22 00:38:09 potato apache2[1605]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's ful
Mar 22 00:38:10 potato apache2[1605]:  *
Mar 22 00:38:10 potato systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

When apache fails, we would expect to see something like:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then issuing one of the provide commands, will give detail regarding the reason, apache could not be started:

```
    ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-22 00:49:46 UTC; 2min 10s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1810 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1863 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 22 00:49:46 potato apache2[1863]:  *
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato apache2[1863]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato apache2[1863]: Output of config test was:
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato apache2[1863]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato apache2[1863]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato apache2[1863]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 22 00:49:46 potato systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

In this example, I moved /etc/apache2/sites-enabled to /etc/apache2/sites-disabled and attempted to start apache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'm having a different problem than what I or originally thought.

Comment: @evandewey - Please edit your question to clarify the issue for the rest of us.

Comment: What I meant is that I thought that it wasn't restarting when it actually, was, and I was having a different problem the entire time. You answered my original question when you said that apache doesn't give any confirmation when it is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Ubuntu you are on, Upstart's native commands should be be processed through initctl, so for that command to have output then you should use `sudo restart apache2`